# What's wrong with my Firebase Web Script (Database Loop)?

Tags: web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code that is running multiple loops and taking forever to finish.

```
  ratingChanged(altHash, newRating, event) {
    var alt_md5hash = altHash;
    var userRateID = this.state.userID;
    // console.log("RATING HASH: ", altHash);
    // console.log("RATING: ", newRating);
    // console.log("userRateID: ", userRateID);

    // Update/Add unique note ratings by user
    var newRateKey = firebase.database().ref('notes/' + alt_md5hash).push().key;
    var updates = {};
    updates['notes/' + alt_md5hash + "/RatingsByUsers/" + userRateID] = newRating;
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

    // Count number of ratings and average
    var numRatings = 0;
    var sumRatings = 0;
    var notesDBRate = firebase.database().ref('notes/' + alt_md5hash + "/RatingsByUsers");
    notesDBRate.on('value', function(noteSnapshot) {
      noteSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        numRatings += 1;
        sumRatings += childSnapshot.val();
        console.log("numRatings1: ", numRatings);
        console.log("sumRatings2: ", sumRatings);
      }.bind(this));
      var averageRating = sumRatings / parseFloat(numRatings); // force float
      console.log("==========AVG RATE: ", averageRating);
      var updateRateNum = {};
      updateRateNum['notes/' + alt_md5hash + "/uniqueRatings"] = numRatings;
      updateRateNum['notes/' + alt_md5hash + "/starRating"] = averageRating;
      console.log("UPDATED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
      firebase.database().ref().update(updateRateNum); 
    }.bind(this));  

    //Add download number to reference of note
    var ownerID = "";
    var notesDB = firebase.database().ref('notes/' + alt_md5hash);
    notesDB.on('value', function(noteSnapshot) {
      ownerID = noteSnapshot.val().ownerID;
      var rateSum = noteSnapshot.val().uniqueRatings;
      var rateAvg = noteSnapshot.val().starRating;
      console.log("ownerID REAL: ", ownerID);

      var updateOwnerRating = {};
      updateOwnerRating['userNotes/' + ownerID + "/" + alt_md5hash + "/uniqueRatings"] = rateSum;
      updateOwnerRating['userNotes/' + ownerID + "/" + alt_md5hash + "/starRating"] = rateAvg;
      firebase.database().ref().update(updateOwnerRating);
    }.bind(this)); 

    //update user's total downloads
    var avgUserNoteRating = 0;
    var avgUserNoteRatingCount = 0;
    console.log("OWNERID READ 2nd: ", ownerID);
    var ownerDB = firebase.database().ref('userNotes/' + ownerID);
    ownerDB.on('value', function(ownerSnapshot) {
      ownerSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        avgUserNoteRating += childSnapshot.val().starRating;
        avgUserNoteRatingCount += 1;
        console.log("inner1: ", avgUserNoteRating);
        console.log("inner2: ", avgUserNoteRatingCount);
      }.bind(this));
      // update USER total rating
      var allAroundRating = avgUserNoteRating/parseFloat(avgUserNoteRatingCount) || 0;
      console.log("==========allAroundRating: ", allAroundRating);
      console.log("UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))");
      var updateTotalUserRatings = {};
      updateTotalUserRatings['users/' + ownerID + "/holisticUserNoteRating"] = allAroundRating;
      firebase.database().ref().update(updateTotalUserRatings); 
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

Here is my console.log for people to follow.

```
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  618.4470238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  201
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  623.4470238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  202
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  625.1970238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  203
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  625.6970238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  204
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  628.6970238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  205
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.06681475029036
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  529.1053571428572
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  171
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  534.1053571428572
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  172
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  535.8553571428572
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  173
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  536.3553571428572
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  174
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  539.3553571428572
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  175
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0820306122448984
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  360.8220238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  116
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  365.8220238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  117
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  367.5720238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  118
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  368.0720238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  119
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  371.0720238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  120
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.092266865079365
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  236.31755952380954
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  76
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  241.31755952380954
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  77
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  243.06755952380954
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  78
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  243.56755952380954
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  79
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  246.56755952380954
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  80
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0820944940476194
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  95.50992063492063
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  31
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  100.50992063492063
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  32
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  102.25992063492063
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  33
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  102.75992063492063
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  34
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  105.75992063492063
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  35
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0217120181405894
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))


(DELETED A CHUNK SO FITS INSIDE STACKOVERFLOW CHARACTER LIMIT)

Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:203 ownerID REAL:  vbHQ2aiIekap6AqLGiwEHVRprhV2
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  905.1553571428574
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  296
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  910.1553571428574
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  297
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  912.0839285714288
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  298
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  912.5839285714288
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  299
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  915.5839285714288
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  300
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0519464285714295
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  874.4053571428574
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  286
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  879.4053571428574
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  287
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  881.3339285714288
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  288
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  881.8339285714288
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  289
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  884.8339285714288
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  290
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.051151477832513
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  770.4886904761905
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  251
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  775.4886904761905
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  252
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  777.417261904762
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  253
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  777.917261904762
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  254
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  780.917261904762
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  255
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.062420634920635
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  709.1345238095239
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  231
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  714.1345238095239
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  232
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  716.0630952380953
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  233
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  716.5630952380953
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  234
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  719.5630952380953
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  235
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.061970618034448
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  633.4470238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  206
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  638.4470238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  207
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  640.3755952380952
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  208
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  640.8755952380952
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  209
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  643.8755952380952
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  210
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0660742630385487
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  544.1053571428572
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  176
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  549.1053571428572
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  177
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  551.0339285714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  178
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  551.5339285714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  179
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  554.5339285714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  180
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.080744047619048
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  375.8220238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  121
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  380.8220238095238
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  122
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  382.75059523809523
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  123
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  383.25059523809523
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  124
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  386.25059523809523
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  125
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.090004761904762
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  251.31755952380954
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  81
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  256.31755952380956
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  82
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  258.246130952381
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  83
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  258.746130952381
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  84
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  261.746130952381
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  85
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0793662464986
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  110.50992063492063
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  36
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  115.50992063492063
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  37
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  117.43849206349206
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  38
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  117.93849206349206
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  39
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  120.93849206349206
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  40
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0234623015873017
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.059814484126984
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  845.9964285714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  276
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  850.9964285714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  277
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  853.0901785714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  278
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  853.5901785714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  279
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  856.5901785714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  280
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.059250637755102
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  770.3089285714285
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  251
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  775.3089285714285
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  252
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  777.4026785714285
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  253
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  777.9026785714285
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  254
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  780.9026785714285
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  255
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.062363445378151
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  680.9672619047619
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  221
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  685.9672619047619
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  222
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  688.0610119047619
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  223
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  688.5610119047619
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  224
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  691.5610119047619
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  225
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0736044973544976
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  512.6839285714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  166
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  517.6839285714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  167
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  519.7776785714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  168
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  520.2776785714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  169
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  523.2776785714286
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  170
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.078103991596639
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  388.17946428571435
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  126
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  393.17946428571435
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  127
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  395.27321428571435
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  128
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  395.77321428571435
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  129
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  398.77321428571435
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  130
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.067486263736264
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  247.37182539682541
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  81
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  252.37182539682541
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  82
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  254.46557539682541
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  83
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  254.96557539682541
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  84
Notefeed.js:220 inner1:  257.96557539682544
Notefeed.js:221 inner2:  85
Notefeed.js:225 ==========allAroundRating:  3.0348891223155934
Notefeed.js:226 UPDATING SECOND :))))))))))))))))
```

It seems when this `ratingFunction` is activated (by clicking on a Star), the code (especially the "ON Value" part) is triggering, reading and updating, but since it is updating, it is re-reading again.

Don't know where the problem(s) specifically is so anyone who sees the error, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're updating a node in the same code that you're receiving the updated values, this sounds like the expected behavior to me.

If you're trying to update a node based on its current value, you'll want to use a transaction instead. A transaction combines the reading of the current value and the writing of the new value, into a single operation. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions